# How to copy or CONCATENATE complex string within Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've created a spreadsheets consist of multiple complex dates & strings.

[image]

When I use concatenate, the date become numbers

```
=CONCATENATE('2021'!A2:'2021'!F61)
```

The results is like

```
44519in44471out44472Guest1in44475out44476SGuest2
```

How can I produce the result like this in one cell

```
November 2021                                        
in        6/11        out        10/11 Guest 1
in        26/11        out        28/11 Guest 2        
December 2021                                        
in        29/12        out        31/12 Guest 3
```

I just need the copy & paste cell features, but I can't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use an Apps Script [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

First, open a bound script by selecting `Tools > Script editor`, and copy the following function to the script:

```
function CONCAT_WITH_DATES(rangeNotation) {
  const values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
                               .getRange(rangeNotation)
                               .getDisplayValues()
                               .map(row => row.filter(cell => String(cell)))
                               .map(row => row.join("     "))
                               .join("\n");
  return values;
}
```

Once the script is saved, you can use this function the same you would use any sheets built-in function:

[image]

#### Note:

The input range has to be provided in quotes in order to retrieve the values with the displayed format via [Range.getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues). If the range is provided directly, the date values won't keep the format.

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that an extra column `F`, which should be blank, is selected in order to identity row break

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN("♦",FALSE,'2021'!A1:F5),"♦{2,}",CHAR(10)),"♦$",),"♦",CHAR(9))
```